# Flutter: replace newlines in String

Tags: string, flutter, dart

How do I replace '\n' with '|' in a String in Flutter

```dart
myString = '''
this is my first line
this is the second line
this is the third one
''';

myString.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\n'), '|');
print(myString)
```

Output:

```
this is my first line
this is the second line
this is the third one
```

And I need it to show:

```
this is my first line|this is the second line|this is the third one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
 var myString = '''
this is my first line
this is the second line
this is the third one
''';

print(myString.replaceAll('\n', '|'));
```